# Convergence of this sequence of functions: $f_n(x)=\frac{2x^2}{x^2+(1-2nx)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of real valued functions defined on $[0,1]$. $$f_n(x)=\frac{2x^2}{x^2+(1-2nx)^2}$$

**I want to talk about convergence of this sequence of functions:**

Dividing by $n^2$, we get

$$f_n(x)=\frac{2x^2/n^2}{x^2/n^2+(1/n-2x)^2}$$

Fix $x$, now taking limit as $n\to \infty$

we get $\lim f_n(x)=\frac{0}{0+(0-2x)}=0$

So the point wise limit of $f(x)=0$

For Uniform convergence,

Consider $M_n=\sup \left|\frac{2x^2}{x^2+(1-2x)^2}\right|$

This looks complicated. One way is to find critical points(keeping $n$ as constant) but this makes expression more complicated.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$f_n\biggr(\frac1{2n}\biggr)=2.$$ Now use a proof by contradiction to show that the sequence is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: What the idea behind the proof? Thanks in advance

Comment: Recall that , for uniform convergence, given any $\varepsilon \gt 0 $, there exists  $n_0\in \Bbb N $ such that  $|f_n(x)-0|<\varepsilon$, for all $n\geq n_0$ and $x\in [0,1]$. Now take $\varepsilon=1$. Can you complete?

Comment: Thanks. Got it.